# Is there a lightweight Groovy web framework other than Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

[Grails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_%28framework%29) is great. Yet, sometimes, we just need a quick, lightweight web framework. Is there such a thing out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are utilising the Google App Engine, there is [Gaelyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/)

Comment: thanks! I found it.  any experiences of using it?

Comment: I tend to use it for GAE sites now instead of grails, as grails seems a bit heavy when starting up. GitHub has some good example projects: http://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=gaelyk&type=Repositories

Comment: Here's the slide that I made about Gaelyk 2.0. http://www.slideshare.net/L0rDKadaj/groovy-on-google-app-engine-with-gaelyk

Answer (score 22):

[Ratpack](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack)

Ratpack is inspired by the excellent Sinatra framework for Ruby, and aims to make Groovy web development more classy.

Comment: @ruX: until now (2017) its alive and maintained

Comment: @lepe even more, it's finally released and has binding for kotlin!

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used them personally but Gaelyk is built on top of Groovlets I believe: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets

Answer (score 2):

[Portofino](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino) is written in Java and Groovy. The basic idea of Portofino is to automatically analyze the structure of an existing database, create a basic application structure, and then customize, handle permissions, etc.

If you have an existing relational database, this is a quick and easy way to bring it on-line with a nice user interface.

Answer (score 2):

How about just using [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) and write everything in groovy.

You can use the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to generate a brand new project with the required stack baked in

Answer (score 1):

Caelyf - Lightweight Groovy toolkit for Cloud Foundry. [Caelyf](https://github.com/caelyf/caelyf)

Gretty - Simple groovy++ web framework for both building web servers and clients. Built on top of netty and NIO. [groovypp/gretty](https://github.com/groovypp/gretty)

Graffiti - lightweight web framework for Groovy inspired by Sinatra
[webdevwilson/graffiti](https://github.com/webdevwilson/graffiti)

Answer (score 1):

<s>With Grails 3 you can to create an ultralight application with the next command
    grails create-app appName --profile=web-micro</s>

Update: With Grails 3.1.0 the option is

```
grails create-app appName --profile=web-api
```

The generated application is stripped with only the necessary dependencies to create a restful api.

Comment: Too bad there's no proper documentation on this.